# label message shows behind menu bar as z-index not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a label and a menu bar in a page..

Label is used to display success of failure message for some process in the page..

When I scroll down the page, the menu bar also comes along the screen above all elements..

But the problem is, the label is not displaying above the menu bar.. Ii shows behind menu bar.. Help me with this problem..

Here is the coding for menu bar and label..

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Style="z-index: 9999; position:fixed"></asp:Label>
```

I tried `position: relative` also for label.

Menu bar css is calling from javascript:

```
$('#reqNavScroll').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': $('.section-body').width(), 'z-index': '100' });
```

Comment: try set `z-index:9999` to parent of `lblMassage` and check the result,

Comment: I expect to see HTML markup instead of `asp` code because this problem can not be reproduced.

Comment: @Radian, both label and menu are under same parent..

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle please?

Comment: Sorry, can't provide jsfiddle..

Comment: In jsfiddle, it works fine..